# Stripe API - calling specific values

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am running python 3.5, django 1.10.

This is the 1st time I have used an api, and I am struggling to understand what to do. Yes, I am a noob.

I am attempting to display [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object) invoice details on a template page.

I have been given some code that can display the basic information, but I am having difficulties displaying the plan name that the invoice relates to.

I have included a screen shot of the invoice api displaying the necessary available details of the invoice, but I am unsure how to display the plan name (circled in red below):

[image]

Here is my template code:

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ invoice.date|date:'dS F, Y P' }}</td>
        <th style="display: none;">{{ invoice.stripe_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ invoice.period_start|date:'dS F, Y' }}</td>
        <td>{{ invoice.period_end|date:'dS F, Y' }}</td>
        <th style="display: none;">{{ invoice.charge }}</td>
        <td>{{ invoice.plan.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ invoice.paid|yesno:'Yes,No' }}</td>
        <td>{{ invoice.refunded|yesno:'Yes,No' }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is what the display looks like:

[image]

**I am hoping someone can push me in the right direction, to display the plan name.**

Comment: `{% for invoice in invoices %}` — where `invoices` variable is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t it just be:

```
{{ invoice.lines.data.0.plan.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe [invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#invoice_object) have a [`lines`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#invoice_object-lines) attribute, which is a [list object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#pagination-object) containing a list of [line items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#invoice_line_item_object).

If the invoice was created for a subscription, it will contain a line item for the subscription (i.e. a line item for which the [`type`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_invoice) attribute is `"subscription"`, and its [`plan`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#invoice_line_item_object-plan) attribute will contain the [plan object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#plan_object) for the subscription.

If you don't manually [create invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_invoiceitem) and don't [update subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#update_subscription) in a way that would cause proration items to be created, that line item will be the sole element in the list, and you can access the plan's [`name`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_plan) with:

```
invoice.lines.data[0].plan.name
```

If you do have more than one line item in your invoice, you'd need to iterate over every line item until you find the line item for the subscription.

Also, this isn't directly related to your question, but in order to access the invoice's ID, you'd need to use:

```
invoice.id
```

rather than:

```
invoice.stripe_id
```